# cakephp escape false for select box

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

Through cakephp how should able to handle quotes in option value.I have a:

```
$options => array(20"=>20",30"=>30",40"=>40")
```

Here i am using key and value are same. This array contains double quotes so html is display's:

```
<option value="20"">20"</option>
```

With this i am not able to save as well display on select box value.

```
echo $this->TwitterBootstrap->input("Attribute.Attribute.$i.value", array(
    'type' => 'select', 
    'options' => $options , 
    'value' => $attribute_value['value'],
    'label' => $entityAttribute['Attribute']['name'],
    'empty' => $entityAttribute['Attribute']['required'] ? false : __('-- None --'),
));
```

Comment: Is your array really looks as you paste it here?

Comment: yes, key and values are same. Should i know how to escape double quotes in option value using cakephp?

Comment: But you have to make keys and values strings first `array('20"' => '20"',  '30"' => '30"', '40"' => '40"')`, because your code shouldn't work.

Comment: Why is it so necessary to save the double quote? I mean if you know inside your db that this is seconds why not just save the actual value as 20 and then inside your view concatenate the double quote to appear at the user.

Answer (score 0):

Your array should look like:

```
$options => array("20"=>20,"30"=>30,"40"=>40);
```

and if `$i` is a variable, then write it like:

```
echo $this->TwitterBootstrap->input("Attribute.Attribute".$i."value",...
```